# Microcontroller used to transmit video?

Tags: microcontroller, video-transmitter

I need help choosing a microcontroller for  a project I'm doing.

This microcontroller needs to do the following:

1) Interface with a low resolution camera, obtain video feed from it, compress it and send it a wireless transmitter.

2) Obtain analogue data from 4-5 sensors and use that information to drive motors through PWM.

3) Obtain control data from a wireless receiver and use it to control 1-2 motors.

I am totally new to this stuff and I have no idea where to look. Basically I have no idea how to relate the specifications of a microcontroller to my specific needs. What microcontroller would suit my needs?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi camera module is just becoming available, which might suit you. Otherwise, you're best off getting a separate wireless video solution.

Comment: Take a look at the TI DaVinci product lineup for video-specific ICs.

Answer (score 6):

Your bottleneck in term of processing power will be the live video processing and real time compression. Video compression done in software takes A LOT of computing time.

Simple evaluation:

you use a low res VGA sensor : 640 x 480 pixels black and white.

you have 640 x 480 = 307200 pixels.

you didn't specify the framerate. But let's decide 25 fps for the computation.

Now you have to process 307200 * 25 = 7.68 Megapixel/sec ! or 0.13us per pixel.

Imagine that you have a high-end ARM cortex-M3 microcontroller at 100 MIPS. or 0.01 us/cycle.

Then you have 0.13us / 0.01 = **13 single instructions available per pixel !**

This assumes that you CPU is doing nothing else. Which is not your case. Thus your compression algorithm has to be **very** simple. Or you should find a chip that is able to do this for you in hardware or reduce a lot the frame rate.

Answer (score 2):

Blup1980's analysis is correct for raw frames. What I suggest is that you obtain a camera with integrated compression that will give you JPEG images, which you can read and transfer quickly using DMAs inside the processor.

Comment: Do you know such camera. I also need similar project. Thanks